# Generate fixed time, fixed frame count, webp animated preview with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, webp

I have a seemingly very simple use case that i cannot find a way to reproduce from instructions scattered on the internet, nor from the ffmpeg manual.

Basically I want an arbitrary webm video to be converted into 4 frames [0, 1/4 1/2 3/4 1]ths of the video.

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm -vf fps=1/$(echo 'scale=6;' $(ffprobe -loglevel quiet -of 'compact=nokey=1:print_section=0' -show_format_entry duration /video.webm) ' / 4' | bc)  thumbnail-%d.png
```

Then i want these frames to generate a webp file that cycles inifinitely through each frame at 1 frame per second.

```
img2webp -loop 0 -d 1000 -o d.webp thumbnail-*
```

What is the single execution ffmpeg command equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

Use

`ffmpeg -i video.webm -vf "select='if(eq(n\,0),1,lt(mod(t\,$D/4)\,1)*gte(t-prev_selected_t\,1))',setpts=N/TB,fps=1" -c:v libwebp_anim -loop 0 d.webp`

where $D is the media duration obtained from ffprobe.

Comment: Thanks Gyan. The result is not the same, not only it does not loop. It also only shows 3 frames with the 3rd one looking corrupted. Can you confirm that the duration is in seconds? Maybe i am making a mistake.
Even so at least now i have some form of animation.

Comment: The output works here in browsers (FF 82,Chrome 86) as expected with looping. Make sure you're using current git builds of ffmpeg.